# How do I create a list of folder names which contain at least one file of a given type

Tags: batch-file

I have a large directory \books.

In that directory are many subdirs. Some of these subdirs contain MP3s.

I want to be able to print a list of each folder name where the folder contains at least one MP3.

The other caveat is that some of these folders themselves contain subdirs where users created a subdir for each -chapter-. Eg:

```
\mybook
   \chapter1
   \chapter2
   ..etc...
```

So the script needs to check for the existence of an MP3 either in the folder OR go down one more subdir level and then if it finds an MP3, print the parent folder name and exit back.

I hope all that made sense. I'd know how to do this with a 'real' programming language but I'm stumped in DOS batch land.

I got this far and gave up.

```
@echo off
for /F %%i in ('dir /s/b "g:\books\*.mp3"') do (
   echo %%i
)
```

...which gives me the first word of the file folder but also recurses so I get the name of each chapter (which I do not want).

1. How do I get the -full- folder name?
2. How do I get it to ONLY search down one level and return the parent folder name (which is the book title).

Comment: Why was this marked down?

Comment: I don't know, but I upvoted it to compensate! **`;)`**

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%a\*.mp3" (ECHO %%a
 ) ELSE (
  SET "found="
  FOR /f %%m IN (
   'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\%%a\*"'
  ) DO IF NOT DEFINED found IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%a\%%m\*.mp3" (
   SET found=y
   ECHO %%a
  )

 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

`for/f` by default assigns the first token to the metavariable. The default delimiter includes space, so turning delimiters off with the `"delims="` option will deliver the entire line.

So - outer loop: get a directory-list in basic form (`/b`) of all of the directorynames (`/ad`) in the source directory; assign each in turn to `%%a`.

If the directory contains a filename *.mp3, report it, otherwise

Inner loop: set "not found" status; same deal - find subdirectory-names of `%%a` in `%%m`, if the required file exists, report it and flag "found" status to prevent further reports if more than one subdirectory of `%%a` contains the required filename.

Comment: Thanks. It -mostly- works. Seems to fail on some folders, but I can't figure out a pattern yet. But this is real progress! I'll report back when I figure it out and mark as answered. CHEERS!

Comment: Fail in which way?

Comment: It's not listing certain folders. I'll let you know when I figure it out.